# Ionic 3 lazy loading : view displayed before enf of global configuration loading

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I'm trying to implement lazy loading in my Ionic 3 application. In my app, I have a configuration provider which get / set configuration from local storage.

This is the code of the provider :

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Storage } from '@ionic/storage';
import 'rxjs/add/operator/map';

@Injectable()
export class ConfigProvider {
  public name: string = null;

  constructor(private storage: Storage) {}

  initialize() {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        Promise.all([
            this.storage.get('name').then(value => this.name = value),
        ]).then(value => {
            resolve();
        });
    });
  }

  setName(name: string): void
  {  
    this.name = name;

    this.storage.set('name', this.name);
  }
}
```

I call the initialize method in the constructor of the MyApp Component :

```
constructor(
  public platform: Platform,
  public menu: MenuController,
  public statusBar: StatusBar,
  public splashScreen: SplashScreen,
  private modalCtrl: ModalController,
  private configProvider: configProvider
) {
  configProvider.initialize().then(() => {
       this.initializeApp();
  });
}
```

But, if I call my Page Component directly from the url, the name property of my provider is null...

```
@IonicPage({
  name: ‘test’,
  segment: ’test’
})
@Component({
  selector: 'page-test’,
  templateUrl: 'test'
})
export class TestPage {
  constructor(
    private configProvider: configProvider) {
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
    // this.configProvider.name is null !!!!
  }
```

Could someone tell me why ? 
Thnax for your help :)

Comment: Not sure what is your use case / context, but I would recommend using standard approach for providers and NOT lazy load them. If you read more about lazy loading with Ionic 3 there are still gaps there. Keep your component lazy loaded but initialize your provider in a standard manner (app.components.ts - import and declare as provider).

Comment: Also you have to make sure you init your provider as a "singleton" since you want to init it in one component and then use its data inside of another.

Comment: Hi @SergeyRudenko,
my provider is already declared in my app.components.ts - import....

Comment: I see, so when you say you call it from the url you mean via routes correct? So the null is returned even after the app gets loaded and then you attempt to navigate to this page? or you are trying to go there directly? just trying to see if when you go to this page your config provider is still not initialized due to its async nature.